# Could not load data in the iframe body in IE 9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

```
iframe = $('<iframe id="myFrame" name="myFrame">');
$("body").append(iframe);
$(iframe).contents().find("body").html('<form action="' + url + '"  method="post"><input type="text" name="requestData" /></form>');
$(iframe).contents().find("input:first").val(jsonData);
$(iframe).contents().find("form:first").submit();
```

I am unable to see the data in the iframe in IE8,9. I could see the form and also input in Chrome and firefox. I have also tried this

```
iframe = $('<iframe id="myFrame" name="myFrame">');
$("body").append(iframe);
$("#myFrame").contents().find("body").html('<form action="' + url + '"  method="post"><input type="text" name="requestData" /></form>');
$("#myFrame").contents().find("input:first").val(jsonData);
$("#myFrame").contents().find("form:first").submit();
```

And also tried using `$(document).ready(function{ // Content});`

But of no use... I cannot see the data in IE

Comment: Your example works for me in IE10 with IE8 emulation mode. What exactly you don't see? Content not rendered or textbox value don't changed or form don't submitted?

Comment: I am able to see the iframe in the body.. but i could not see the form tag and also the input tag in it..

Comment: 1) check if url variable contains quote symbol; 2) check if iframe body already exists in moment when you try to modify its innerHTML, otherwise you'll need to subscribe to iframe.onload event and modify html there; that's all I can say since I don't have native IE8 to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have checked everything u told.. When i debug i am getting `undefined` for `$("#myFrame").contents().find("body").html()` but i am getting an object for `$("#myFrame").contents().find("body")`

Comment: By the way i am not even getting this in IE 9

Comment: You getting object, by most of jQuery methods returns you wrapped objects, it's not neccessary found something. To ensure that query returned you body, you should check obj.length (it must be > 0 if body was found)